# Access to session in flask_wtf

Tags: python, session, flask

In forms.py I wanna get access to sessions.
this is forms.py code:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField,FileField,TextAreaField,TextField,validators
.
.
.
class Send(Form):
    group = SelectField('Group',[validators.Required('you must select a group')],coerce=int,choices=c)
    title = TextField('Title',[validators.Required('you must enter a title')])
    content = TextAreaField('Content',[validators.Required('you must enter a content')])
    attachment = FileField('Attachment')
```

But when I add this code :

```
from flask import session
uid = session.get('user_id')
```

It shows me this error:

```
raise RuntimeError('working outside of request context')
RuntimeError: working outside of request context
```

So how can I solve it?

Comment: What are you expecting to do with the user id? Remember, the user id will change from request to request, so declaring it in the form once doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MarkHildreth I need userid for fetching user records from database and show them in the form (selectField). so I saved userid in the session and I need to use it in the form. So do you have any idea to make it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I find how to solve that problem.

I think one of the best way is to use session in the route file.

This is my form code:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField

class Test(Form):
    name = SelectField('Name')
```

So I have an app with "our" name, I have access to session in this app:

```
from flask import Blueprint,session,render_template
from form import Test
our = Blueprint('our',__name__)
@our.route('/')
def index():
    form = Test()
    #session['name'] = 'hedi'
    if session.get('name').lower() == "morteza":
        form.name.choices = ((1,'mori'),(2,'hedi'))
    else:
        form.name.choices = ((1,'you'))
    return render_template('index.html',form=form)
    #return str(session.get('name'))
```

Now I changed my form field data via app. **form.name.choices=....**

Answer (score 3):

You should use `uid = session.get('user_id')` only on request, for example:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    '''dispatcher functions works with request context'''
    uid = session.get('user_id')
    return str(uid)
```

If this code calling not from request (another process, another thread, celery, unit test and etc), then you should create request context manually or avoid use context stack variables:

```
with app.test_request_context():
    uid = session.get('user_id')
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, about app.test_request_context() I have problem , sometimes I use Blueprint instead , and I get error because Blueprint doesn't have test_request_context() , So how can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: You must get application and call `test_request_context()`, probably `current_app` will not work for your case. But look like you want build bad solution for this case. Better describe what you want make?

Comment: Ok , I have 3 apps that have different jobs , so in all apps I want to check authentication and get userid via session for providing some features. So what is the best solution , or what is your idea?

Comment: The best solution is use `Flask-Login`, because it store user ID in `session` and check authentication by user ID in `session`. But however you should use `session` (or `current_user` for `Flask-Login`) only in request dispatchers (view/route functions), because it have sense only when user make request. However I currently not understand how you get `RuntimeError: working outside of request context` exception for this case if your code worked without `session`.